# Sending fax using Windows Fax Server Extentions - faxcomexlib

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, fax

I'm trying to find faxcomexlib.dll.  After Googling around, I installed the Core SDK from the Platform SDK, but I still don't see this dll listed in the System32 folder. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServerClass();
                //faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName); 
                faxServer.Connect("//My-Server");                   
                FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);               
                faxDoc.RecipientName = "Test";
                faxDoc.FaxNumber = "1234567890"; 
                faxDoc.DisplayName = "Test";
                int Response = faxDoc.Send(); 
                faxServer.Disconnect();
```

I'm using VS 2010/.NET 4.0, and I'm on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Windows Fax Service and physical fax device on your computer to get that dll in the system 32